# Result set used as an instance variable

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset, connector

In a program, the connector, preparedstatement and resultset are used as instance variables and closed every time after its use in a separate method as given below and then reused by creating a new connector object, assigning it to `con` for the subsequent calls. Is it safe to do this or is it better to create separate connector objects locally in methods and closing it in finally block?

```
private void closeObjects() throws Exception{
 if(rs!=null){
 rs.close();
 rs=null;
 }
 if(preparedstmt!=null){
 preparedstmt.close();
 preparedstmt=null;
 }
 if(con!=null){
 con.close();
 con=null;
 }
}
```

I actually did face an issue where using as instance variables when I ran the program the first time, it failed giving an error `Result set not open` but started working after on the second run onwards.

[Apologies for not displaying the whole code]

Comment: Depends. Can the method be called concurrently? In general, I see no reason to have them as instance variables instead of local variables!

Comment: Using a methodd to create connection object is beneficial..especially f you wanna use singleton which can improve performance

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have JDBC instances as local variables in method that performs SQL operations. This approach makes their lifecycle clear and you do not need to worry, if you forget to call closeObjects() somewhere. If you want to avoid code duplication, then create method that accepts them as argument and call it from finally block.

```
private void closeObjects(Connection con, ResultSet rs, Statement statement) throws Exception {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
        rs=null;
    }

    if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
        statement=null;
    }

    if (con != null) {
       con.close();
       con=null;
    }
}
```